# SSIS value does not fall within the expected range with OLE DB Datasource

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using Visual studio 2013 with update 3 and a collegue of mine with update 4 installed each. We are using the data dools for sql server 2014.

I've created a few DTS packages which my collegue updated so far it worked without problems.
But all of a sudden I get "value does not fall within the expected range" warning from the datasource and can't edit columns there,.. . I needed to recreate the datasource for the message to disappear again.

My question here is can it be that the appearance of additional columns in the table which the datasource accesses was the cause of this problem? (I've seen out of sync warnings for datadestinations whenever a destination table got new columns or lost columns, but this is the first time something changed for a source table).

Or can that problem have a completely different cause?

Comment: Is it in all data sources, or only specific ones?  If it is specific to a few, please post screenshots of each tab in one of the affected data sources.

Comment: We were only using oledb data sources so not really anything specific that could be evaluated there (and strangely the problem did not appear again so far)

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long while since I've worked on an SSIS project, but I do recall seeing this error as well.
My experience was that it was caused to the metadata of the input being out of date in a certain way, and what you describe as your suspicion fits with this.

The solution I found to avoid this was to be very specific on all my input components, selecting the exact columns I wanted rather than selecting all. I think in the end I actually changed them all to use hand written SQL queries rather than the GUI column selector.

Also I don't remember if this was the same error but a similar one: sometimes after a schema changing when trying to open a component the GUI would throw an error and not open but when I tried again it would have resolved the error.

Sorry I couldn't be more definitive in my answer but hopefully this information helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: With gui not openening....do you mean the display of the contents of the pacakge? (I have noticed time and again that sudenly I couldn't access the package aka displaying its contents on screen (and getting undefined errors when I tried to execute tehm) until I restarted visual studio.  That happened mostly after I updated my version of the project via TFS (was confused there as it didnt happen every time but only time and again.....it COULD be that it was only when the EF schema changed but not 100% there)

Comment: I never had an issue displaying the content of the package itself, only when trying to open one of the components to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple method and it is working fine. In the OLE DB Source Editor while I retained the same connection manager, changed Data access mode (from Table/View) to SQL command and used SQL command to select the required columns. Error message no longer appeared and I could see the column values....